# Updating user token without logging him out nextjs and keycloak

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, keycloak

i'm using keycloak and nextjs and i'm updating user attribute once a button is clicked and would like to update the user access token with the new token that includes the new attribute so it will give him more features without being logged out.
Couldn't find any good information on how to do it.

That's what i'm doing now, get the data updating it and creating the new token with the new attribute. Not sure how to proceed from here as i need to "inject" to new token to the user session using next auth

```
export const upgradeService = async id => {
  let authService = new AuthService(credentials)
  const access_token = await (
    await authService.login(credentials)
  ).access_token

  const setRaw = result => {
    result.attributes.subscription_type = 'upgraded'
    let raw = JSON.stringify({
      attributes: result.attributes,
    })
    return raw
  }



  fetch('endPoint', requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
      const raw_fixed = setRaw(result)
      var requestOptions_upgrade = {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw_fixed,
        redirect: 'follow',
      }
      return fetch(
        'endPoint',
        requestOptions_upgrade
      ).catch(error => console.log('error', error))
    })
    .then(async result => {
      const auth_Service = new AuthService(credentials)
      const newAccessToken = await (
        await auth_Service.login(credentials)
      ).access_token
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
}
```

Comment: have you already checked whether the new token contains the new attribute? you do not tell this in your question.

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann Yes it does contain, i will add that. Thanks

Comment: have you tried session callback like here https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#session-callback ?

Comment: @MatthiasWiedemann yes, i added token refresh handler, now when the token expire it get refreshed , the question is how do i initiate the refresh when i click a button?